# Use case for /usr/bin/lessecho

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, history, less

I can not come up with an example of how I could/would  use `lessecho`. The description in the man page is fairly straight forward but is not helping me come up with a use case:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> lessecho  is a program that simply echos its arguments on standard output. But any metacharacter in the output is preceded by an "escape"  character, which by default is a backslash.

I searched through shellscripts on github and could not find any use of the command.  Can you give one or two (or three) examples of lessecho? The more varied the use case the better.

Comment: Look into the source code of `less` itself. The `lglob` function in `filename.c` calls `lessopen`. It's a helper program to solve a specific problem in implementing `less`, not really meant to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a companion program for `less`. It is used internally in some configurations (determined at compile time) to call a shell from commands where you can specify a wildcard pattern that stands for a list of file names: the “examine” (`:e`) command and a few others (`-o`, `-O`, `-T`). The weird quoting is something that `less` parses internally. The point of using `lessecho` instead of `echo` is to make spaces in file names distinguishable from spaces used to separate file names. The command `printf '%s\000'` would serve the same purpose, with less parsing effort, but isn't available on some of the ancient unices that less still works on.

I don't know why `less` uses this approach on modern unix systems instead of calling the `glob` library function.

Answer (score 0):

Main goal of `lessecho` is to escape metacharacters. But the trap is that *no character* is considered as metacharacter by default (see `-mx` option manual). So you need to specify at least one metacharacter with the `-m` option in order to see a result different from the argument.

Example with colon as metacharacter:

```
$ lessecho -m: a:b
a\:b
```